# Partial Match not working

Tags: java

I have three Strings a,b,c below and I am trying to get String exp to have a partial match with String b, but every time I run the code I get no match.

```
  String a = "ID = '5' && name='abc' || level='5'";
  String b = "ID = '6' && name='def' || level='6' && year='2012'";
  String exp = "ID = '6' && name='def' || level='6'";
```

My Code:

```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(b);
  Matcher m = p.matcher(exp);
  if(m.matches()){
        System.out.println("Perfect Match");
  }
  else if(m.hitEnd()){
        System.out.println("Partial Match");
  }
  else{
        System.out.println("No Match");
  }
```

Even when I remove && year='2012', it gives me no match.

Comment: Are you sure you know what a regular expression is?

Comment: @TimCooper To be fair, `Pattern` and `Matcher` make no mention of regular expressions. He would have to read the documentation to find that out.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be compiling `b` into a Pattern, you should be compiling `exp`. This will allow you to search through `b` for `exp`.

The way you have it now searches for `b` within `exp`, which will never find a match since `exp` is a subset of `b`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a partial match then you don't need Regular Expressions.

Use this:

`if (b.contains(exp))`

And to check if two strings are equal you can use:

`if (b.contentEquals(exp))`